# Get all possible combinations from 3 categories in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 category (cate1, cate2, cate3) and I have 14 row in database. I like to get all the possible combinations.

Databas:

```
id   category   
1    cate1
2    cate2
3    cate3
6    cate1
7    cate2
8    cate3
9    cate1
10   cate2
11   cate3
12   cate1
13   cate2
14   cate3
```

Results:

```
[0]
    cate1 = 1  (id)
    cate2 = 2  (id)
    cate3 = 3  (id)
[1]
    cate1 = 6  (id)
    cate2 = 7  (id)
    cate3 = 8  (id)
[2]
    cate1 = 9  (id)
    cate2 = 10 (id)
    cate3 = 11 (id)
```

..and so on to all combination is listed.

Please help

Comment: you want group them by category?

Comment: mind posting your desired result as well along with what have you tried?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please explain further. All possible combinations of what ?

Comment: i fix.. one sec :)

Comment: Just updated the question with a results exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a `cross join`, for each category:

```
select c1.id, c2.id, c3.id
from (select t.* from t where category = 'cate1') c1 cross join
     (select t.* from t where category = 'cate2') c2 cross join
     (select t.* from t where category = 'cate3') c3;
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. Get only 1 item per row. I like it to be 3 item per row se my "result" exempel. Please help

Comment: Love this answer byt find a problem. Is there a way to prevent the same row to show up more than once for each "hit"?